# How to query a mongoose returned value

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose

Am trying to query a value that's returned from mongoose callback function, but all I get is `TypeError: #<Object> is not a function`. I know it might not be easy to do that, but with the way am querying the db I need to dive more deep from the returned results, without really having to call up the `User` model again. I don't know if there's a way to go around that.

```
 User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if(user.plan == 'hit'){
                User.find({plan: 'hit', verified: 'yes'}).lean().exec(function(error,*suc*){
                    if(suc.length < 1){
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log('no user')
                    } else {
                        console.log(suc)

                        **Error throws up right below here**

                        *suc*.find({admintit: 'admin', adminLimit: 200, admincycle: 0}, function(errok,hungad){
                            if(errok){
                                console.log(err)
                            } else {
                                if(hungad.length < 1){
                                    console.log('no hung admin');
                                } else {
                                    console.log(hungad)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Really trying to query the **suc** callback result, but all I get is an error, I have tried converting it to an object `Object.assign({}, suc)` but it still returns same error, that it's not a function.

Comment: Are those asterisks `*suc*.find` intentional, or for emphasis (not in your actual code)?

Comment: @JackBashford they are for emphasis, so as to draw attention to the callback am talking about.

Comment: On which line is the error? Can you point it out for us with a comment please?

Comment: @JackBashford The error throws up, right on the suc.find() function, every other thing is working correctly. normally the suc is in array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`suc` is going to be an array of results where the error occurs, meaning if you call `find` you will get [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and not mongoose find.

If you actually want to call [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) assuming the object looks like:

```
const suc = [{admintit: 'admin', adminLimit: 200, admincycle: 0}, ...]
```

You should change it to:

```
const admin = suc.find(result => result.admintit === 'admin' && result.adminLimit === 200 && result.admincycle === 0)
if (admin) {
    console.log(admin)
} else {
    console.log('no hung admin');
}
```

If you want to find all you can change `find` to `filter`:

```
const admins = suc.filter(result => result.admintit === 'admin' && result.adminLimit === 200 && result.admincycle === 0)
if (admins.length > 0) {
    console.log(admins)
} else {
    console.log('no hung admin');
}
```

If you were looking to call `find` for mongoose then you will have to define it on the schema

```
User.method('find', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: That's a good step forward, please can you elaborate more on how I can archive that with the mongoose method(), still a mongodb newbie :)

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do. What is the expected result of hungad? I think what you might be looking for is `User.find({admintit: 'admin', adminLimit: 200, admincycle: 0}...`, instead of `*suc*.find`

Comment: Yep, but I don't really want to be calling up the User model again. I just want to go on with the already returned value, or maybe how I can achieve that from the mongoose method()

Comment: I've updated my answer to either use `find` or `filter` on the users that have been returned to find admins.

Comment: @FillipoSniper did this fix it for you?

Comment: Sure it did, marked as the correct answer, happy </>